# ASP.NET C# Search XML Node on multiple criteria

Tags: c#, xml, search, criteria

I am trying to search for an xml node:

```
<Countries>
  <Country FullName="AFRIQUE DU SUD" Code="ZA" IsOut="1" />
  <Country FullName="ALLEMAGNE" Code="DE" IsOut="0" />
</Countries>
```

Selecting on the basis of CountryCode only:

```
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Countries/Country/@[Code='ZA']");
```

How do I also apply the condition so that I can check for CountryCode AND IsOut = 1?

```
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Countries/Country/@[Code='ZA',@IsOut='1'");
```

The above condition does not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
"//Countries/Country[@Code = 'ZA' and @IsOut = '1']"
```