# Select sibling node value based on multiple sibling conditions

Tags: xml, vb.net, siblings, selectsinglenode, selectnodes

I want to select the URL value (5.jpg) of the node that has Type=IMAGE and Key=XS
ps: the order of the Images nodes is random, so I can't just select the nth node.

What I tried but fails:

```
Dim root As XmlNode = objXML.DocumentElement
Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = root.SelectNodes("/Products/Product")
```

`nodeList(i).SelectSingleNode("//URL[../Type='IMAGE' and ../Key='XS']").InnerText`

and

`nodeList(i).SelectSingleNode("/Images/[Type=IMAGE] and /Images/[Key=XS]").ChildNodes(0).SelectSingleNode("URL").InnerText`

```
<Products>
    <Product>
        <Id>9200000093797005</Id>
        <Images>
            <Type>IMAGE</Type>
            <Key>XS</Key>
            <Url>5.jpg</Url>
        </Images>
        <Images>
            <Type>IMAGE</Type>
            <Key>S</Key>
            <Url>1.jpg</Url>
        </Images>
        <Images>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

Already checked here:

- [XPath Selecting value of an XML node based on multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51030301/xpath-selecting-value-of-an-xml-node-based-on-multiple-conditions)
- [Select node based on sibling's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31117609/select-node-based-on-siblings-value)
- [ASP.NET C# Search XML Node on multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158488/asp-net-c-sharp-search-xml-node-on-multiple-criteria)
- [Retrieving XmlNode SelectSingleNode Parents Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036412/retrieving-xmlnode-selectsinglenode-parents-node)
- [How to get the sibling of an xml node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775718/how-to-get-the-sibling-of-an-xml-node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost correct in your attempts. I think the use of the `XmlNodeList` is what was causing your problems. If you switch to using an `XmlNode` and `SelectSingleNode` then you would've had the answer sooner.

```
    Dim root As XmlNode = objXml.DocumentElement
    Dim node As XmlNode = root.SelectSingleNode("//Products/Product/Images[Type='IMAGE' and Key='XS']/Url")
    Dim url As String = node.InnerText
```